# QtQuick Grid, mouse events no propagating over adjacent mouse areas

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I've written this simple qml app that allows to paint pixels over a grid:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Grid {
        id: grid
        anchors.fill: parent
        rows: 32
        columns: 64

        Repeater {
            model: grid.columns * grid.rows;
            delegate: delegateGridImage
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: delegateGridImage

        Item {
            id: gridItem
            property int currentColumn: index % grid.columns
            property int currentRow: Math.floor(index / grid.rows);

            // Resize to screen size
            width: grid.width / grid.columns
            height: grid.height / grid.rows

            Rectangle {
                id: pixel
                anchors.fill: parent
                property bool pixel_state: true
                color: if (pixel_state == true ) { "white" } else { "black" }

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    hoverEnabled: true
                    propagateComposedEvents: true
                    acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.RightButton
                    onEntered: console.log(index)
                    onPressed: pixel.pixel_state ^= true

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine:

[image]

I would like to be able to paint multiple pixels with a single mouse click pressed.

I've tried the onEntered event, but it only listens to the active mouse area until the click button is released. Is there a way to not block the events from the other mouse areas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a global `MouseArea` and deduct the current item below the cursor via [childAt(...)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#childAt-method) of the `Grid`.

```
Window {
    ... // remove the MouseArea of pixel

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
        acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.RightButton

        property bool pixel_activate: true

        onPressed: {
            var child = grid.childAt(mouse.x, mouse.y)
            child.pixel_state ^= true
            pixel_activate = child.pixel_state
        }

        onPositionChanged: {
            if (!pressed) return;
            var child = grid.childAt(mouse.x, mouse.y)
            child.pixel_state = pixel_activate
        }
    }
}
```

You just have to decide what action you want to perform once you hold the button pressed (currently it performs first action activate/deactivate and all following). Also take a look at the [MouseEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mouseevent.html) passed by the [signals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#signals) `pressed` and `positionChanged` so you can differentiate what key was pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Lasall's solution works great. This is the final result:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Grid {
        id: grid
        anchors.fill: parent
        rows: 32
        columns: 64

        Repeater {
            model: grid.columns * grid.rows;
            delegate: delegateGridImage
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: delegateGridImage

        Item {
            id: gridItem
            property int currentColumn: index % grid.columns
            property int currentRow: Math.floor(index / grid.rows);

            property bool pixel_state: false

            // Resize to screen size
            width: grid.width / grid.columns
            height: grid.height / grid.rows

            Rectangle {
                id: pixel
                anchors.fill: parent

                color: if (gridItem.pixel_state == true ) { "white" } else { "black" }
            }

        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
        acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.RightButton

        property bool pixel_activate: true

        onPressed: {
            var child = grid.childAt(mouse.x, mouse.y)
            child.pixel_state ^= true
            pixel_activate = child.pixel_state
        }

        onPositionChanged: {
            if (!pressed) return;
            var child = grid.childAt(mouse.x, mouse.y)
            child.pixel_state = pixel_activate
        }
    }
}
```